# Hive not enforcing bucketing

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am going through the Hive tutorial in the O'Reilly Hadoop book by Tom White. I am trying to make a bucketed table, but I can't get Hive to create the buckets. I can create the table and load the data into it, but all of the data is then stored in one file.

I am running a pseudo-distributed Hadoop cluster. I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1 and Hive 0.10.0 with a MySql metastore.

The data (shown below) are initially in the table 'users'. They are to be put in a table with 4 buckets, i.e. one user per bucket.

```
select * from users;
OK
id      name
0       Nat
2       Joe
3       Kay
4       Ann
```

I set the properties below in an attempt to enforce bucketing (I don't think that setting mapred.reduce.tasks explicitly is necessary, but I included it just in case).

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=4;
```

Then I create the table 'bucketed_users' and load the data into it.

```
CREATE TABLE bucketed_users (id INT, name STRING) 
CLUSTERED BY (id) 
SORTED BY (id ASC) INTO 4 BUCKETS;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE bucketed_users SELECT * FROM users;
```

The output:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 4
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
Execution log at: /tmp/katrina/katrina_20131003204949_a56048f5-ab2f-421b-af45-9ec3ff85731c.log
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
Hadoop job information for null: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2013-10-03 20:49:34,011 null map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-10-03 20:49:35,026 null map = 0%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_local1250355097_0001
Execution completed successfully
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
Loading data to table records.bucketed_users
Deleted hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/bucketed_users
Table records.bucketed_users stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 1, num_rows: 4, total_size: 24, raw_data_size: 20]
OK
id  name
Time taken: 8.527 seconds
```

The data have been loaded into 'bucketed_users' correctly (`SELECT * FROM bucketed_users` shows all users) but the number of files created is just 1 (`num_files: 1` above) rather than the desired 4. Looking at the bucketed_users directory in HDFS (`dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/records/bucketed_users;`) shows just one file, 000000_0. How can I enforce bucketing?

The full log is below:

```
2013-10-03 20:49:30,769 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - Execution log at: /tmp/katrina/katrina_20131003204949_a56048f5-ab2f-421b-af45-9ec3ff85731c.log
2013-10-03 20:49:31,139 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(328)) - Using org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat
2013-10-03 20:49:31,144 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(350)) - adding libjars: file:///Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar
2013-10-03 20:49:31,144 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:addInputPaths(852)) - Processing alias users
2013-10-03 20:49:31,145 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:addInputPaths(870)) - Adding input file hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users
2013-10-03 20:49:31,145 INFO  exec.Utilities (Utilities.java:isEmptyPath(1900)) - Content Summary not cached for hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users
2013-10-03 20:49:31,365 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(52)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-10-03 20:49:32,410 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:createTmpDirs(219)) - Making Temp Directory: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/-ext-10000
2013-10-03 20:49:32,420 WARN  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(746)) - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2013-10-03 20:49:32,648 WARN  snappy.LoadSnappy (LoadSnappy.java:<clinit>(46)) - Snappy native library not loaded
2013-10-03 20:49:32,655 INFO  io.CombineHiveInputFormat (CombineHiveInputFormat.java:getSplits(370)) - CombineHiveInputSplit creating pool for hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users; using filter path hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users
2013-10-03 20:49:32,661 INFO  mapred.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(199)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-10-03 20:49:32,716 INFO  io.CombineHiveInputFormat (CombineHiveInputFormat.java:getSplits(411)) - number of splits 1
2013-10-03 20:49:32,847 INFO  filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager (TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:downloadCacheObject(423)) - Creating hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar in /tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar-work--7485859847513724632 with rwxr-xr-x
2013-10-03 20:49:32,850 INFO  filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager (TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:downloadCacheObject(435)) - Extracting /tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar-work--7485859847513724632/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar to /tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar-work--7485859847513724632
2013-10-03 20:49:32,870 INFO  filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager (TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:downloadCacheObject(463)) - Cached file:///Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar as /tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar
2013-10-03 20:49:32,880 INFO  filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager (TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:localizePublicCacheObject(486)) - Cached file:///Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar as /tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar
2013-10-03 20:49:32,987 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2013-10-03 20:49:33,034 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(340)) - Waiting for map tasks
2013-10-03 20:49:33,037 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(204)) - Starting task: attempt_local1250355097_0001_m_000000_0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,073 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(534)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
2013-10-03 20:49:33,077 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:updateJobWithSplit(455)) - Processing split: Paths:/user/hive/warehouse/records/users/users.txt:0+24InputFormatClass: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat

2013-10-03 20:49:33,093 INFO  io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader (HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:initIOContext(154)) - Processing file hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users/users.txt
2013-10-03 20:49:33,093 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runOldMapper(419)) - numReduceTasks: 1
2013-10-03 20:49:33,099 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:<init>(949)) - io.sort.mb = 100
2013-10-03 20:49:33,541 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:<init>(961)) - data buffer = 79691776/99614720
2013-10-03 20:49:33,542 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:<init>(962)) - record buffer = 262144/327680
2013-10-03 20:49:33,550 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:configure(69)) - maximum memory = 2088435712
2013-10-03 20:49:33,551 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:configure(74)) - conf classpath = [file:/tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar/]
2013-10-03 20:49:33,551 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:configure(76)) - thread classpath = [file:/tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar/]
2013-10-03 20:49:33,585 INFO  exec.MapOperator (MapOperator.java:setChildren(387)) - Adding alias users to work list for file hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users
2013-10-03 20:49:33,587 INFO  exec.MapOperator (MapOperator.java:setChildren(402)) - dump TS struct<id:int,name:string>
2013-10-03 20:49:33,588 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:configure(91)) - 
<MAP>Id =10
  <Children>
    <TS>Id =0
      <Children>
        <SEL>Id =1
          <Children>
            <RS>Id =2
              <Parent>Id = 1 null<\Parent>
            <\RS>
          <\Children>
          <Parent>Id = 0 null<\Parent>
        <\SEL>
      <\Children>
      <Parent>Id = 10 null<\Parent>
    <\TS>
  <\Children>
<\MAP>
2013-10-03 20:49:33,588 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 10 MAP
2013-10-03 20:49:33,588 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 0 TS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,588 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(386)) - Operator 0 TS initialized
2013-10-03 20:49:33,589 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(390)) - Initializing children of 0 TS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,589 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:initialize(425)) - Initializing child 1 SEL
2013-10-03 20:49:33,589 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 1 SEL
2013-10-03 20:49:33,592 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (SelectOperator.java:initializeOp(58)) - SELECT struct<id:int,name:string>
2013-10-03 20:49:33,594 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(386)) - Operator 1 SEL initialized
2013-10-03 20:49:33,595 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(390)) - Initializing children of 1 SEL
2013-10-03 20:49:33,595 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(425)) - Initializing child 2 RS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,595 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 2 RS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,595 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (ReduceSinkOperator.java:initializeOp(112)) - Using tag = -1
2013-10-03 20:49:33,606 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(386)) - Operator 2 RS initialized
2013-10-03 20:49:33,606 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 2 RS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,606 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 1 SEL
2013-10-03 20:49:33,606 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 0 TS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,607 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 10 MAP
2013-10-03 20:49:33,637 INFO  exec.MapOperator (MapOperator.java:cleanUpInputFileChangedOp(494)) - Processing alias users for file hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users
2013-10-03 20:49:33,638 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:forward(774)) - 10 forwarding 1 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,638 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:forward(774)) - 0 forwarding 1 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,639 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:forward(774)) - 1 forwarding 1 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,641 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:map(148)) - ExecMapper: processing 1 rows: used memory = 114294872
2013-10-03 20:49:33,642 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 10 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,643 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 10 forwarded 4 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,643 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:logStats(845)) - DESERIALIZE_ERRORS:0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,643 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 0 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,643 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 0 forwarded 4 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,643 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 1 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 1 forwarded 4 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 2 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.ReduceSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 2 forwarded 0 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.SelectOperator (Operator.java:close(570)) - 1 Close done
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.TableScanOperator (Operator.java:close(570)) - 0 Close done
2013-10-03 20:49:33,644 INFO  exec.MapOperator (Operator.java:close(570)) - 10 Close done
2013-10-03 20:49:33,645 INFO  ExecMapper (ExecMapper.java:close(215)) - ExecMapper: processed 4 rows: used memory = 114767288
2013-10-03 20:49:33,647 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1289)) - Starting flush of map output
2013-10-03 20:49:33,659 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:sortAndSpill(1471)) - Finished spill 0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,661 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:done(858)) - Task:attempt_local1250355097_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2013-10-03 20:49:33,668 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/records/users/users.txt:0+24
2013-10-03 20:49:33,668 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(970)) - Task 'attempt_local1250355097_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2013-10-03 20:49:33,668 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(229)) - Finishing task: attempt_local1250355097_0001_m_000000_0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,668 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(348)) - Map task executor complete.
2013-10-03 20:49:33,680 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(534)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
2013-10-03 20:49:33,680 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,690 INFO  mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(408)) - Merging 1 sorted segments
2013-10-03 20:49:33,695 INFO  mapred.Merger (Merger.java:merge(491)) - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 70 bytes
2013-10-03 20:49:33,695 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,697 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:configure(100)) - maximum memory = 2088435712
2013-10-03 20:49:33,697 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:configure(105)) - conf classpath = [file:/tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar/]
2013-10-03 20:49:33,697 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:configure(107)) - thread classpath = [file:/tmp/hadoop-katrina/mapred/local/76384558/archive/-2634153638864376244_689726567_810621743/file/Users/katrina/Code/hive/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.10.0.jar/]
2013-10-03 20:49:33,698 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:configure(149)) - 
<OP>Id =3
  <Children>
    <FS>Id =4
      <Parent>Id = 3 null<\Parent>
    <\FS>
  <\Children>
<\OP>
2013-10-03 20:49:33,698 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 3 OP
2013-10-03 20:49:33,698 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(386)) - Operator 3 OP initialized
2013-10-03 20:49:33,698 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(390)) - Initializing children of 3 OP
2013-10-03 20:49:33,698 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(425)) - Initializing child 4 FS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,699 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(321)) - Initializing Self 4 FS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,701 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:initializeChildren(386)) - Operator 4 FS initialized
2013-10-03 20:49:33,701 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 4 FS
2013-10-03 20:49:33,701 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:initialize(361)) - Initialization Done 3 OP
2013-10-03 20:49:33,706 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:reduce(243)) - ExecReducer: processing 1 rows: used memory = 117749816
2013-10-03 20:49:33,707 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:forward(774)) - 3 forwarding 1 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,707 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (FileSinkOperator.java:createBucketFiles(458)) - Final Path: FS hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,707 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (FileSinkOperator.java:createBucketFiles(460)) - Writing to temp file: FS hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_task_tmp.-ext-10000/_tmp.000000_0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,707 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (FileSinkOperator.java:createBucketFiles(481)) - New Final Path: FS hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0
2013-10-03 20:49:33,737 INFO  ExecReducer (ExecReducer.java:close(301)) - ExecReducer: processed 4 rows: used memory = 118477400
2013-10-03 20:49:33,737 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 3 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,737 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 3 forwarded 4 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,737 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(549)) - 4 finished. closing... 
2013-10-03 20:49:33,737 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:close(555)) - 4 forwarded 0 rows
2013-10-03 20:49:33,990 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - Hadoop job information for null: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2013-10-03 20:49:34,011 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - 2013-10-03 20:49:34,011 null map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-10-03 20:49:34,111 INFO  jdbc.JDBCStatsPublisher (JDBCStatsPublisher.java:publishStat(137)) - Stats publishing for key hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/-ext-10000/000000
2013-10-03 20:49:34,143 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Operator.java:logStats(845)) - TABLE_ID_1_ROWCOUNT:4
2013-10-03 20:49:34,143 INFO  exec.ExtractOperator (Operator.java:close(570)) - 3 Close done
2013-10-03 20:49:34,145 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:done(858)) - Task:attempt_local1250355097_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2013-10-03 20:49:34,146 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - reduce > reduce
2013-10-03 20:49:34,147 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(970)) - Task 'attempt_local1250355097_0001_r_000000_0' done.
2013-10-03 20:49:35,026 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - 2013-10-03 20:49:35,026 null map = 0%,  reduce = 100%
2013-10-03 20:49:35,030 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(392)) - Ended Job = job_local1250355097_0001
2013-10-03 20:49:35,033 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Utilities.java:mvFileToFinalPath(1361)) - Moving tmp dir: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_tmp.-ext-10000 to: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_tmp.-ext-10000.intermediate
2013-10-03 20:49:35,036 INFO  exec.FileSinkOperator (Utilities.java:mvFileToFinalPath(1372)) - Moving tmp dir: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/_tmp.-ext-10000.intermediate to: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hive-katrina/hive_2013-10-03_20-49-28_110_131412476548383989/-ext-10000
```

Comment: Bucketing works for me with Hadoop 1.2.1 and CDH4, but on Hadoop 2.2.0 I see this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that:

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE bucketed_users SELECT * FROM unbucketed_users;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 4
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_1384565454792_0070, Tracking URL = http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1384565454792_0070/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1384565454792_0070
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 4
2013-11-16 05:04:12,290 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-11-16 05:04:33,868 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 7.16 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 7 seconds 160 msec
Ended Job = job_1384565454792_0070
Loading data to table default.bucketed_users
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hue/.Trash/Current
Table default.bucketed_users stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 4, num_rows: 0, total_size: 24, raw_data_size: 0]
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 4   Cumulative CPU: 7.16 sec   HDFS Read: 259 HDFS Write: 24 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 7 seconds 160 msec
OK
Time taken: 19.291 seconds
hive> dfs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users;                         
Found 4 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hue hdfs         12 2013-11-16 05:04 /apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users/000000_0
-rw-r--r--   3 hue hdfs          0 2013-11-16 05:04 /apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users/000001_0
-rw-r--r--   3 hue hdfs          6 2013-11-16 05:04 /apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users/000002_0
-rw-r--r--   3 hue hdfs          6 2013-11-16 05:04 /apps/hive/warehouse/bucketed_users/000003_0
```

It is very odd that you see a conversion to MapJoin, you should not see that since your query has no joins in it. Is that really the query you're running? If you're seeing that I would suggest to:

```
hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

If that fixes it you should file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, this works for me , However since you specify that your table is sorted you also need to set

```
set hive.enforce.sorting=true;
in addition of 
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
```

I'm wondering if the combination of bucket/sort table and only setting one of the enforce setting messes it up somehow.